# What's the difference between db:test:clone, db:test:clone_structure, db:test:load, and db:test:prepare?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, unit-testing

You'll have to admit, to a newbie to rails and databases, the official explanation on rubyonrails.org makes all four of these tasks sound exactly the same. Quote:

```
rake db:test:clone  Recreate the test database from
                    the current environment’s database schema

rake db:test:clone_structure    Recreate the test database from the
                                development structure

rake db:test:load   Recreate the test database from the current schema.rb

rake db:test:prepare    Check for pending migrations and load the test schema
```

I don't even know the difference between structure and schema. And what's  the difference between loading the current environment's schema and just loading schema.rb?

Just how similar (or different) are these tasks?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Very good question. Had me stumped so I dove into the rails source and pulled up [`database.rake`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L402). Now it's more clear:

- `db:test:clone` is just a combination of `db:schema:dump` and `db:test:load`:

  ```
  task :clone => %w(db:schema:dump db:test:load)
  ```
- `db:test:clone_structure` uses the `{rails_env}_structure.sql` file:

  ```
  task :clone_structure => [ 'db:structure:dump', 'db:test:purge' ] do
    # skipped some code, here's what happens for MySQL:
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:test)
    # ...
    IO.readlines("#{Rails.root}/db/#{Rails.env}_structure.sql").join.split("\n\n").each do |table|
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(table)
    end
  end
  ```
- `db:test:load` is the same as `db:schema:load`, but invokes it on the test database:

  ```
  task :load => 'db:test:purge' do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations['test'])
    # ...
    db_namespace['schema:load'].invoke
  end
  ```
- `db:test:prepare` alerts you if any migrations are pending, and if not, either runs `db:test:clone_structure` (using the `{rails_env}_structure.sql` file) or `db:test:load` (using the `schema.rb` file), depending on the schema format (this is a little confusing to me, maybe someone else can expand on it):

  ```
  task :prepare => 'db:abort_if_pending_migrations' do
    # ...
    db_namespace[{ :sql  => 'test:clone_structure', :ruby => 'test:load' }[ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format]].invoke
  end
  ```

Hope this clears it up! Again, going through the [database.rake](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L402) file is easy and will clear up any other questions you might have. That link goes to the line that is the beginning of the `:test` namespace.

Comment: Bottom line: They are all pretty much the same thing. :-p

Comment: warning -- I found that db:test:clone did not correctly copy the nullability of columns from my development database.  This may be an old bug that has subsequently been fixed, as I found it using Rails 2.3.12.

Answer (score 22):

They are actually not quite the same thing.  Any of those tasks that contain the word 'schema' act on the .../db/schema.rb file. schema.rb is effectively the state of your schema after applying all migrations. It can be executed to restore your schema rather than running all of the db migrations (which can take a long time if you have lots of migrations).

Any of the tasks with the word 'structure', act on the {Rails.env}_structure.sql file. This file is used when your schema contains constructs that can't be expressed in the schema.rb file.  For example, if you use features specific to a particular RDBMS. Under the covers, rails produces this file using whatever schema dump utility it appropriate for your RDBMS. To restore the schema, it reads the file in and executes the SQL statements agains using an RDBMS-specific tool.

Rails knows whether to go the schema.rb route or the structure.sql route based on whether or not you've set

config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

in your .../config/application.rb

Comment: examples of things that can differ: triggers, functions and stored-procedures. (which is why we're still stuck using structure).